# How to develop with coffee script with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I've been thinking about CoffeeScript lately, and I just upgraded a Rails project I've been working on to Rails 3.2.8 (from Rails 3.0.9 which didn't have the asset pipeline) following [this guide](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1).

I had to do some hackish stuff to get things to work properly. I'm testing out a new page, '/pages/game' and so it has some example CoffeeScript in the the asset directory.

(app/assets/javascripts/page.js.coffee)

```
class MyObject
  constructor: ->
  hello: -> alert 'hello world of coffeescript!'


a = new MyObject

a.hello()
```

Then I added a line to my production environment:
(config/environments/production.rb)

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( pages.js )    # this is needed to precompile coffee script files... it is difficult to understand how manifest files work...
```

Then typing

```
$  bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Worked to compile page.js  The only problem is that the class I created with CoffeeScript doesn't work exactly as I anticipated.  So I opened up my developer console in FireFox and attempted to instantiate the class manually, but it acted like there was no such object named MyClass.

So where have I gone wrong?  Was it presumptuous of me to assume I could manually instantiate classes I've written in CoffeeScript?  Was my hackish means of adding pages.js to the precompile array inappropriate?  If you're a CoffeeScript pro, how would you test your classes and such?

**Update:**
Part of my problem was the 'variable privacy' that is inherant in coffee script classes.  This privacy can be implemented in standard javascript, and should be understood before dabbling too far into coffee script.  http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

That said, the coffee script class needed to be attached to the window object to make it globally accessible, like so:

**Corrected**

```
class MyObject
  constructor: ->
  hello: -> alert 'hello world of coffeescript!'


window.MyObject = MyObject;
```

Once the class is published in this manor (by attaching it to window as a global) it can be instantiated via `a = new MyObject()` and then have its function called normally to alert to the screen `a.hello()`

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow, like Wikipedia, is primarily meant to serve a a reference. The tone of your writing should be professional.

Comment: You shouldn't have added `pages.js` to your precompiled assets. Rather, you should have added it to your JS manifest file via `//= require pages`. Simply adding it to the precompiled assets doesn't include it in your page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyObject` absolutely exists **if you include `pages.js`'s contents into your page**. You likely need to add

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "pages" %>
```

to your HTML or **not** set

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( pages.js )
```

and instead add the following to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee`

```
//= require pages
```

and make sure `application.js` is being included in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

The **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)** on the asset pipeline is quite helpful. To provide a bit of explanation here though...

Rails wants you (by default) to pack all of your javascript into a single `application.js` file when deploying to production. Sprockets is available to let you add require directives like the one above to find, include, and compile the files listed into the `application.js` file.

By default Rails will only compile `application.js`, `application.css` and any NON-`.js/.css` file in `app/assets`, `lib/assets`, and `vendor/assets`. This means, unless you add a `//= require` directive for `pages.js` to your `application.js` file, Rails is going to ignore it.

Thats why you tried adding `pages.js` to the list of files for compilation with `config.assets.precompile`. This tells Rails explicitly to compile that file, making it available through a javascript include like

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "pages" %>
```

which I am assuming you've not put into your HTML. Going this route is not typically what you for a few reasons, one of which is that by doing so you're saying "No thanks" to the help Rails is trying to provide you with the asset pipeline `//= require` lines.

So, either method is doable; you've just yet to follow through with all the steps necessary to get `pages.js`'s contents included in your page, which is why `MyObject` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did have things somewhat working correctly by the <%= javascript_include_tag "pages" %> method.  The only problem was that my javascript code looked like this http://pastebin.com/HZG6bzfp 
and it seems to be getting run twice because I see the alert message twice.

Comment: Ok, I went back to it, cleaned out a bunch of pages.js cache files and the alert msg only appeared once.  I also attached the class to window by doing 'window.MyObject = MyObject' within my coffee script file because that seems to be how you declare public classes which allows me to debug using the console just as I always have with straight javascript projects.  Thanks so much for helping me get CoffeeScript off the ground.

Comment: @deefour hi - does this apply to rails 4?